# For Each Item in ArrayList Substitute into pattern

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

Hello so as the title says I am trying to develop a java program that will have an array-list with each column identified as $i. So column 1 would be $1 and so on. Now I am not asking for someone to create this entire program for me, I am looking for input and somewhere to start. I am open to suggestions just need help getting started thank you

Data:

```
Mike,Jan-14
Sean, Mar-15
Jessica, Jun-08
```

Then I will have a field to type in a pattern..

Pattern:

```
Hello $1, your Birthday is $2
```

Result would than list out the iterations of all values as so..

Results:

```
Hello Mike, your Birthday is Jan-14
Hello Sean, your Birthday is Mar-15
Hello Jessica, your Birthday is Jun-08
```

Comment: You should look into the [`MessageFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

Comment: Is formula `Hello $1, your Birthday is $2` fixed or can you change `$1` to something like `{1}`?

Comment: -Pshemo The token can be whatever as long as the program does what it's intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you don't want the entire code, so here are some references :

1. [Scanner class for reading from a file or STDIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)
2. Then use [split function of String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), to split your input into tokens
3. Then again use Scanner class to write your output to a file or wherever you want to..